# r data.table selecting columns

Tags: r

base2c and MedSurgc are column names that I would like to select from data.table in R.

```
> base2c
[1] "ID"   "YEAR" "SEX"  "AGE" 
> MedSurgc
 [1] "LW_OC"     "LW_OC_DUR" "LW_OC_YY"  "LW_OC_MM"  "LW_WH"     "LW_WH_A"   "LW_WH_DUR" "LW_WH_YY"  "LW_WH_MM" 
[10] "LW_OV"     "LW_OV_A"
```

Now when I want to run code below,
I don't get expected result.
what would be the problem?

```
MedSurg <- DT[ , .(c(base2c, MedSurgc))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.SD` with `.SDcols`. Example:

```
dt <- data.table(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4)
select1 = "A"
select2 = c("B","C")

dt[, .SD, .SDcols=c(select1, select2)]

       A     B     C
   <num> <num> <num>
1:     1     2     3
```

As for the problem, first remember that , inside `data.table`'s `[]`, `.()` is just a synonym for `list()`. Secondly, inside `j`, `data.table` looks inside the list and converts what it finds to a `data.table`.

Thus:

```
dt[, .(c(select1, select2))]
```

is identical to:

```
data.table(c(select1, select2))
```

and gives:

```
       V1
   <char>
1:      A
2:      B
3:      C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MedSurg <- DT.KN5FMc[ , c(base2c, MedSurgc), with = FALSE]
```

This works